# Questions to Characteristics on a second Order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, characteristics

Given the 2nd order linear PDE

\begin{align} 
u_{tt}&=\frac{1}{9}u_{xx}, & &t>0,\ x \in \mathbb{R}  
\end{align}

***Solution***

We calculate the discriminant
$$D=b^2-ac=\frac{1}{9}>0$$
So it is hyperbolic.

My question is how could I understand if I have to use
$$\frac{dx}{dt} \quad or \quad \frac{dt}{dx}$$
to find the characteristics?